# Error `SDK does not contain 'libarclite' at the path` on `flutter run` on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, cocoapods

I am trying to run my app in the iOS simulator. I get this error every time I run flutter run.

My `flutter doctor` output:

```bash
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.0, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.10.0 on channel stable at /Users/mudassirchapra/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 84a1e904f4 (5 months ago), 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
    • Engine revision d44b5a94c9
    • Dart version 3.0.0
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mudassirchapra/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A240d
    • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.83.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.74.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile) • 27EF... • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 118.0.5993.70
   

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

I have run multiple rounds of the following commands

```bash
flutter clean
flutter pub get
rm Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update --verbose
```

My `Podfile` has `platform :ios, '13.0'` and the deployment target in Runner is 13

[image]

What might be causing this error?